# Better way to SSH through multiple machines

Tags: ssh

I currently have to SSH 3 times to get into the machine I need:

```
ssh gatekeeper
[passwd1]
ssh master_server
[passwd2]
ssh my_machine
[passwd3]
```

Is there a better way to do get into `my_machine`?  Pretty cumbersome to have to do it every time.

Comment: Is this programming-related? If not, you might want to try SuperUser/ServerFault (with specific network information) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice - this worked:

```
Host my_machine
  Hostname my_machine
  ProxyCommand ssh user2@master_server -W %h:%p
  ProxyCommand ssh user1@gatekeeper -W %h:%p
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't really know for 3 SSH, but here is my way for 2 (lets say : me -> master_server -> my_machine).

You need to add a configuration file in your home :

```
~/.ssh/config
```

Then you write in that file :

```
Host my_machine
  Hostname my_machine.example.com
  ProxyCommand ssh other_or_same_login@master_server -W %h:%p
```

And you call

```
ssh login@my_machine
```

Then you will have to enter twice your password (or 3 times in your case). If you don't want to type passwords, you can use the key access option.

For another ssh, I guess you need to write another section in the config file, but since I can't try I don't wan't to say something wrong.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, that worked for 2 machines.  Now I have to figure out where to add the command for the 3rd machine (if possible at all)